# Getting Error "unrecognized option -Xa " in gcc version 4.1.2


Tags: linux, gcc, compiler-construction

In Linux gcc version 4.1.2 I am getting error `"cc: unrecognized option '-Xa'"`. Any idea about this compiler option `'-Xa'` . However it gets compiled in solaris gcc 3.4.3 version.

Answer (score 0):

Howerver, the ouput is "cc...". Are you sure you are using gcc. not other compiler(e.g SUN cc) ?

You can install gcc on Solaris, HPUX, AIX etc. but you typically cannot install the proprietary cc compilers in other environments, including linux.

Comment: my CC on linux is linked to GCC as cc -> gcc . so inturn its gcc

Answer (score 0):

`-Xa` is a Sun C compiler option.
From **Man Page cc.1**:

```
     -X[c|a|t|s]
          Specifies the degree of conformance to the ISO C stan-
          dard[...]

          a    This is the default compiler mode. ISO C plus K&R
               C compatibility extensions, with semantic changes
               required by ISO C. Where K&R C and ISO C specify
               different semantics for the same construct, the
               compiler uses the ISO C interpretation. If the -Xa
               option is used in conjunction with the -xtransi-
               tion option, the compiler issues warnings about
               the different semantics. The predefined macro
               __STDC__ has a value of 0 with the -Xa option.
```