# What gcc options to use to use the same standard than solaris cc -Xa

Tags: c, gcc, std, cc

I need to move a large code base from Solaris to Linux.

The C compiler has the Xa option which means that it uses the "ISO C plus K&R C compatibility extensions".

There is a copy of the man page about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10222318/getting-error-unrecognized-option-xa-in-gcc-version-4-1-2).

On Linux I have some warnings that I don't have on Solaris about the popen method:

```
toto.c:7: warning: implicit declaration of function 'popen'
toto.c:7: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast
```

What options should I use on my gcc to use the same C standard ?
Without any option or with -std=gnu89/99, I don't have the warning.

With -ansi or -std=c89/99 I have the warning.

Is it safe to use the vanilla or gnu standard to emulate the Solaris -Xa option  ?

Edit: the toto source code for user31264:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    FILE * FD;
    FD = popen("toto", "r");
    return 0;
}
```

And the part of stdio.h on Linux:

```
#if (defined __USE_POSIX2 || defined __USE_SVID  || defined __USE_BSD || \
     defined __USE_MISC)
/* Create a new stream connected to a pipe running the given command.

   This function is a possible cancellation point and therefore not
   marked with __THROW.  */
extern FILE *popen (__const char *__command, __const char *__modes) __wur;

/* Close a stream opened by popen and return the status of its child.

   This function is a possible cancellation point and therefore not
   marked with __THROW.  */
extern int pclose (FILE *__stream);
#endif
```

Comment: You should fix these warnings while you're a it. K&R C ist just a no go today.

Comment: The code base is large and old. Sure. But I want first to have it to run identically in Linux, then update what is possible to update.

Comment: Please publish toto.c

Comment: The real problem is the compiler is not finding a declaration of `popen` in any included header. Sometimes it's telling you that (as above), or with other options it's just silently making up an (implicit) declaration -- which could be wrong. As previously stated, you should fix that error...

Comment: Are you also moving from 32 bits (on solaris) to 64 bits (on linux)? You may want to consider doing it in 2 steps. "no option" (i.e. the default) seems like the right choice. If you go with a stricter -std=c90, you'll need something like -D_XOPEN_SOURCE=600 to have access to popen and other such functions.

Comment: @Marc so the gcc with default std should produce something similar to the solaris C compiler with -Xa ?

Comment: I don't think there is any option that will give you something similar to -Xa, but the default is rather permissive.